# Generating number pyramids

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am currently practicing on generating number pyramids. The desired output are as follows:

[image]

However, the current number pyramid I have coded are the other way around, where the middle column is numbered "1". Could someone explain to me where I have did wrong?

```
# Print numbers in different rows
# Row separation
for i in range(1, 10):
    # Print empty spaces before numbers
    for j in range(1, 9 - i + 1):
        # Spacing and new line
        print(" ", end="")

    # Printing of numbers after spacing
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end="")

    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        print(j, end="")

    # Enter new line
    print()
```

I have tried to play around with the FOR loops, but it messes up my pyramid arrangement

Comment: `i` is the number of the row to print, so e. g. for the first row `for j in range(i, 0, -1)` becomes `for j in range(1, 0, -1)`.

Comment: I recommend trying to solve a simpler problem first: write a python program that prints the numbers from 9 down to 1. Hint: look at the documentation for the `range()` function so it will count down for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the top and print increasing and decreasing ranges from a starting point that works its way down.  For the left side, print spaces for the equivalent number of columns that are below the starting point:

```
top = 9
for first in range(top,0,-1):
    print(*[" "]*(first-1),*range(first,top),*range(top,first-1,-1))
```

output:

```
                9
              8 9 8
            7 8 9 8 7
          6 7 8 9 8 7 6
        5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5
      4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4
    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3
  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

*This will work up to 10. after that, the indent becomes trickier as some of the numbers will take up two spaces (or more) while others are narrower.*

The `*` in front of each part of the print statement does "unpacking".  This means that each entry in a range or a list preceded by a `*` will be treated as a separate parameter to the print function.  For example `print(*range(5))` is equivalent to `print(0,1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly print any spacing.

Start by building the last line first. Everything else follows that. Just build a list then print in reverse. In that way you only call *print()* once for each row - i.e., 9 times

```
N = 9 # must be in inclusive range 1 to 9

rows = [list(range(1, N+1)) + list(range(N-1, 0, -1))]

for k in range(N-1):
    rows.append(rows[-1].copy())
    rows[-1][k] = ' '
    rows[-1][-k-1] = ' '

for row in reversed(rows):
    print(*row)
```

**Output:**

```
                9                
              8 9 8              
            7 8 9 8 7            
          6 7 8 9 8 7 6          
        5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5        
      4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4      
    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3    
  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score -2):

the "problem" with your code was that the numbers are printed as j, which represents the original number. When j is 1, it prints "1". This results in the numbers increasing as you move away from the center. what you should have done is subtract 10 from j so that the number decreases as you move away from the center. here is your edited Code

```
# Print numbers in different rows
# Row separation
for i in range(1, 10):
    # Print empty spaces before numbers
    print(" "*abs(2*(9-i)+1), end="")

    # Printing of numbers after spacing
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(f"{10-j} ", end="")

    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        print(f"{10-j} ", end="")

    # Enter new line
    print()
```

Hope this helped....

Comment: This does not produce the required output as there is no spacing between output digits

Comment: @DarkKnight Hmm, could you explain why this removes all the spacing between numbers? Compared to my original code, it seems like he only amended the J in third and fourth FOR loops, but how does that removes the spacing?

Anyways, thank you bement for trying to help me!

Comment: @DarkKnight  you were right, sorry for the oversight, now I've made changes to the code now. and it produces the required output.